# Fallo con variables en javascript (supongo) Al usar una, se solapa la otra

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy intentando hacer un test y necesito que al pulsar un botón me de el número de intentos (las veces que se pulsa el botón) y el porcentaje de aciertos de cada intento (que se vaya actualizando cada vez que se pulsa el botón), pero al contar los intentos, solo cuenta el porcentaje de la primera vez que se hace click en el botón, las demás veces no lo cuenta.

Si quito los intentos, sin problemas me sale el porcentaje correctamente, pero al intentar hacer los dos no puede hacer el porcentaje... ¿alguien puede ayudarme? Quizá sea un error de novata, pero no consigo resolverlo. Os dejo los dos códigos, tanto JavaScript como HTML:

```js
function corregir(){
  var n1, n2, n3, n4;

  if(document.getElementById("r11").checked == true &&
  document.getElementById("r12").checked == false &&
  document.getElementById("r13").checked == false &&
  document.getElementById("r14").checked == true){
      n1=1;
  }else{
      n1=0;
  }

  if(document.getElementById("r22").checked == true){
      n2=1;
  }else{
      n2=0;
  }


  if(document.getElementById("34").selected == true){
      n3=1;
  }else{
      n3=0;
  }

  if(document.getElementById("4").value == "Structured Query Language"){
      n4=1;
  }else{
      n4=0;
  }

  var suma = n1+n2+n3+n4;
  var nota = suma * 100 / 4;
  //si activo esto desactivando el onclick, funciona el porcentaje
            //document.getElementById("porcentaje").innerHTML = "has acertado un "+ nota +"% de respuestas.";        
        
  // Ponemos el contador a 0
  var int = 0;
  int = int + 1;

  // SI QUITO ESTO ME VA BIEN EL PORCENTAJE:
  document.getElementById("boton").onclick = function(){
                    document.getElementById("boton").value = "✿ Reintentar ✿";
                    document.getElementById("intentos").innerHTML = "Intento número " + ++int + ". En este intento has acertado un "+ nota +"% de respuestas.";
                    }
        }
```

```html
<h1><u>Test sobre SQL</u></h1>
    
    <form method="POST">
        <b>1. De estas opciones, ¿cuáles puedes hacer en una base de datos SQL? <i class="pistas">Selecciona más de una respuesta</i></b> <i>(2,50 puntos)</i><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="r11" class="respst" required>Manipular datos<br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="r12" class="respst">Jugar al Pac-Man<br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="r13" class="respst">Hacer dibujos con letras y números<br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="r14" class="respst">Hacer cálculos avanzados y álgebra<br><br>


        <b>2. ¿Cuál es un tipo de base de datos SQL? <i class="pistas">Selecciona solo una respuesta</i></b> <i>(2,50 puntos)</i><br>
        <input name="2" type="radio" id="r21" class="respst" required>MongoDB<br>
        <input name="2" type="radio" id="r22" class="respst">Oracle<br>
        <input name="2" type="radio" id="r23" class="respst">Redis<br>
        <input name="2" type="radio" id="r24" class="respst">Apache Cassandra<br><br>

        <b>3. Elije la base de datos que <u>no</u> sea SQL. <i class="pistas">Despliega y elige una respuesta</i></b> <i>(2,50 puntos)</i><br>
        <select name="resPreg3">
            <option id="30" value="0">--Elige una respuesta--</option>
            <option id="31" value="0">Firebird</option>
            <option id="32" value="0">Microsoft Access</option>
            <option id="33" value="0">MariaDB</option>
            <option id="34" value="1">CouchDB</option>
        </select><br><br>

        <b>4. ¿Qué significan las siglas SQL en inglés? <i class="pistas">Escribe tu respuesta en el cuadro</i></b> <i>(2,50 puntos)</i><br>
        <textarea id="4" placeholder="Escribe aquí tu respuesta" cols="40" rows="2"></textarea><br><br>

    </form>

    <input class="boton" type="submit" value="✎ Corregir " onclick="corregir()" id="boton">
    <span id="intentos"></span><span id="porcentaje"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes algunos errores en la lógica de tu script:

1. La variable para contar intentos debe ser declarada como global (fuera de la función) para que no se reinicie con cada clic en el botón
2. Estás asignando el evento directamente en la etiqueta del botón `onclick="corregir()"`. **Nota:** Esto no es propiamente un error, pero sí puede considerarse una mala práctica. Es mejor agregarlo en Javascript, de forma que tengas toda la lógica en un solo lugar y la depuración sea más fácil
3. El problema que mencionas en:

> // SI QUITO ESTO ME VA BIEN EL PORCENTAJE:

```
document.getElementById("boton").onclick = function(){
    document.getElementById("boton").value = "✿ Reintentar ✿";
    document.getElementById("intentos").innerHTML = "Intento número " + ++int + ". En este intento has acertado un "+ nota +"% de respuestas.";
}
```

No funciona porque estás asignando nuevamente un evento y se va a disparar hasta el siguiente clic. Además, en una línea arriba estás incrementando el contador de intentos con `int = int + 1;` y vuelves a incrementar al crear el texto con `++int`.

```js
// Definir intentos en cero, como variable global
let int = 0;

function corregir(){
  let n1, n2, n3, n4;

  if(document.getElementById("r11").checked == true &&
      document.getElementById("r12").checked == false &&
      document.getElementById("r13").checked == false &&
      document.getElementById("r14").checked == true
  ) {
      n1=1;
  } else {
      n1=0;
  }

  if(document.getElementById("r22").checked == true){
      n2=1;
  }else{
      n2=0;
  }


  if(document.getElementById("34").selected == true){
      n3=1;
  }else{
      n3=0;
  }

  if(document.getElementById("4").value == "Structured Query Language"){
      n4=1;
  } else {
      n4=0;
  }

  let suma = n1 + n2 + n3 + n4;
  let nota = suma * 100 / 4;

  // Esto no interfiere con el resto de la lógica
  document.getElementById("porcentaje").innerHTML = "Has acertado un "+ nota +"% de respuestas.";        
        
  // Incrementar contador
  int += 1;

  // Esto no debe estar dentro de un evento clic
  document.getElementById("boton").value = "✿ Reintentar ✿";
  document.getElementById("intentos").innerHTML = "Intento número " + int + ". En este intento has acertado un "+ nota +"% de respuestas.";
}

// Asignar evento a botón
document.querySelector('#boton').addEventListener('click', corregir);
```

```html
<h1><u>Test sobre SQL</u></h1>
    
    <form method="POST">
        <b>1. De estas opciones, ¿cuáles puedes hacer en una base de datos SQL? <i class="pistas">Selecciona más de una respuesta</i></b> <i>(2,50 puntos)</i><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="r11" class="respst" required>Manipular datos<br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="r12" class="respst">Jugar al Pac-Man<br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="r13" class="respst">Hacer dibujos con letras y números<br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="r14" class="respst">Hacer cálculos avanzados y álgebra<br><br>


        <b>2. ¿Cuál es un tipo de base de datos SQL? <i class="pistas">Selecciona solo una respuesta</i></b> <i>(2,50 puntos)</i><br>
        <input name="2" type="radio" id="r21" class="respst" required>MongoDB<br>
        <input name="2" type="radio" id="r22" class="respst">Oracle<br>
        <input name="2" type="radio" id="r23" class="respst">Redis<br>
        <input name="2" type="radio" id="r24" class="respst">Apache Cassandra<br><br>

        <b>3. Elije la base de datos que <u>no</u> sea SQL. <i class="pistas">Despliega y elige una respuesta</i></b> <i>(2,50 puntos)</i><br>
        <select name="resPreg3">
            <option id="30" value="0">--Elige una respuesta--</option>
            <option id="31" value="0">Firebird</option>
            <option id="32" value="0">Microsoft Access</option>
            <option id="33" value="0">MariaDB</option>
            <option id="34" value="1">CouchDB</option>
        </select><br><br>

        <b>4. ¿Qué significan las siglas SQL en inglés? <i class="pistas">Escribe tu respuesta en el cuadro</i></b> <i>(2,50 puntos)</i><br>
        <textarea id="4" placeholder="Escribe aquí tu respuesta" cols="40" rows="2"></textarea><br><br>

    </form>

    <!-- No es recomendable poner el evento aquí, es mejor con Javascript -->
    <input class="boton" type="submit" value="✎ Corregir " id="boton">
    <span id="intentos"></span><span id="porcentaje"></span>
```

Seguramente todavía hay cosas por mejorar, pero con los cambios mencionados en comentarios ya funciona.